# Listview ArrayAdapter custom item onClickListener working only first time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I have a ListView with ArrayAdapter, which shows news. In between the news there are some native ads which I preload and show at reserved positions. However, the OnClickListener inside of this view works only first time I add the view - if user scrolls down past it and then back up, when clicking on it, nothing happens.

How can I fix this?

```
public class NewsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {

    private List<NativeAdNews> nativeAds;

    public void setData(List<Article> data) {
        dataset.clear();
        dataset.addAll(data);

        loadAdFromNetwork(() -> {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            NativeAdNews nativeAdView = (NativeAdNews) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_news_nativead, null);
            nativeAdView.setNativeAd(ad.getName(), ad.getWebsite());

            nativeAds.add(nativeAdView);

            Article a = new Article();
            a.setId("nativead" + (nativeAds.size() - 1));
            dataset.add(position, a);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Article article = dataset.get(position);

        if(article.getId().startsWith("nativead")) {
            int nativeAdPosition = Integer.parseInt(article.getId().replace("nativead", ""));
            NativeAdNews nativeAdView = nativeAds.get(nativeAdPosition);
            //nativeAdView.setClickListeners(); I tried manually re-setting the click listeners with no luck
            return nativeAdView;
        } else {
            // reuse views
            View rowView = convertView;
            ...

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}

public class NativeAdNews extends FrameLayout {
    private TextView advertiserTextView;

    public void setNativeAd(String advertiserName, String advertiserWebsite) {
        advertiserTextView.setText(advertiserName + " (" + advertiserWebsite + ")");
        setClickListeners();
    }

    public void setClickListeners() {
        advertiserTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
            getContext().startActivity(i);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        // setup ad
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        advertiserTextView = findViewById(R.id.advertiser);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare the `advertiserTextView`?

Comment: It's a member of `NativeAdNews` class. Previously I left it out to keep the code example as short as possible, but I have added it now for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try "ViewHolder" in ArrayAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // viewHolder
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_news_nativead, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.news = (NativeAdNews) v;
        v.setTag(holder)
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.news.setClickListeners();
    return v;
}

public class ViewHolder {
     NativeAdNews news;
}
```